# Is there a way to have a program open a new console window and return information with C / C++?

Tags: c++, windows, windows-console

I am currently trying to prevent user input to the console window. But I have yet to be able to find a way to stop or clear it so I figured maybe if I could open another console window when the user needs to type something and have that return the integers that were typed in. Either that or a way where I can prevent user input and then enable it when it is needed.

```
void AddMenu()
{
    bool correctData = false;

    while (correctData == false)
    {
    system("cls");
    std::cout << "Type the ID: ";

    int id = NULL;
    int data = NULL;

    std::cin >> id;
    std::cout << "What would you like to add for " << id << ": ";
    std::cin >> data;

    if (id != NULL && data != NULL)
    {
        CallAdd(id, data);
        correctData = true;
    }

    std::cin.clear();
    Sleep(700);
    printMainMenu(0);

    }
}
```

Comment: "*I am currently trying to prevent user input to the console window*" - why? What are you trying to accomplish with that exactly?

Comment: @RemyLebeau Well, it is basically to prevent issues with the way the program works. It takes in 2 integers when you want to add to the list, an ID and Data, but if you type lets say 12 and hit enter, while being in the main menu which doesn't take inputs. Whether you select the option to delete or add to the list it will automatically use what the typed prior to choosing what option. So if they choose to add, it will automatically set the ID to 12 which I don't want happening. Same with delete, but it would just automatically delete whatever is at ID 12.

Comment: @Jayt1395 when you are ready to prompt the user for input, you could simply read and discard any input that may already be pending, then display the prompt. That way, only the prompted input will be valid. See [`std::cin:ignore()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore).